# Get all records using find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following class:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
```

then in a part of my code, I tried to **get all the records** using `find` in this way:

```
@movies = Movie.find(:all)
```

but it doesn't work for me. I am faced with the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Movie with 'id'=all):
```

I know, that I can do this in a simple way with `Movie.all()`, but I am insisting on `find` since my next step will be 
`@movies = Movie.find(:all,order: myfield)` and we know that, `all()` just get 1 parameter.

So what's wrong with my code?

Comment: which rails version are you using ?

Comment: Please read through [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to querying using ActiveRecord. There are examples in there which are relevant to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to use ActiveRecord `find` method to get all records. `find` method is used to get some particular record with given id. If you want to order all records in particular sequence, then use:

```
@movies = Movie.order('myfield')
```

Pass sequence accordingly. Default will be ascending.

```
@movies = Movie.order('myfield DESC')
```

Comment: what about, if I want to add a where condition to it?
for instance, **where 'myfield'=10**

Comment: Use where method, Movie.where(myfield: 10)

Answer (score 1):

```
@movies = Movie.all.order('myfield')
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the current answers, you'll need to look at [*chaining*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining):

```
@movies = Movie.where(myfield: 10).order(:myfield)
```

You can call a variety of methods within the ActiveRecord query interface, you just need to make sure you have them in the correct order as to define their scopes properly.